# How can I fix the fact reactions in a specific text message group are coming through as text on my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

There is one particular message group where any message reactions are coming through as text.  For example:

[image]

All of these people in the group are *also* iPhone users. I am on an iPhone xR on iOS 14.2 (but this has been happening a while). Note that other text groups do not have this problem. Is there  any way to fix this? It is incredibly annoying.

Comment: Are you sure that everyone in this chat has iMessage turned on, including you (`Settings -> Messages -> iMessage`)?  Also, are all the people in the chat receiving these messages on their phone number and not email address?

Comment: @fsb - I definitely do -- again this works great in all my other chats. I cannot guarantee that everyone in this group has iMessage turned on though. Why would that matter?  Shouldn't it only be an issue between sender and me?

Comment: If the other people were in Messages but didn't have iMessages turned on, then I believe the tapback is sent via SMS and the icons show as text.  I recall reading an Apple support page many months ago that tapback icons only display when using iMessage.